# Set limits in DyanmoDb batchWriteItem

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there any way we can set threshold limits for batchWriteItem in dynamoDb : 
if TableWriteItems has reached 25 items limit ,insert data (this can be done by checking size of tableWriteItems ,but what if we never received 25 items from backend for a significant time )

What I am looking here is :-> if TableWriteItems has reached either of these three conditions : timeLimit , itemSizeLimit or   dataSizeLimit ,insert one batch in dynamoDb

```
TableWriteItems testTableWriteItems = new TableWriteItems("TestTable");
            for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {

                PrimaryKey primaryKey = new PrimaryKey();
                primaryKey.addComponent("testId", testId.toString());
                primaryKey.addComponent("testName", "testbatch"+i);
                Item item = new Item().withPrimaryKey(primaryKey);

                testTableWriteItems.addItemToPut(item);

            }



            BatchWriteItemOutcome outcome = dynamoDB.batchWriteItem(testTableWriteItems);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DynamoDB Import-Export Tool](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-import-export-tool/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/dynamodb/bootstrap/DynamoDBConsumer.java#L85) has a sample solution for batching items up in groups of 25 items. You could expand that using the [Item sizing method in the DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/janusgraph/diskstorage/dynamodb/DynamoDBDelegate.java#L1078) to implement the size limit. Finally, you would need a second thread to stroke the work queue and fire BatchWriteItem requests if the queue size does not change for a while.